# Video not showing after tabbing on Safari - Issue is killing me (and the other developer I hired)

Tags: javascript, video, safari, tabs, hover

I designed a website for a client and had a developer (better than me) put together some Javascript which shows a video on hover. Works fine on all browsers except safari; it has a strange quirk.

The first time the page loads and the user performs the hover, the video plays no problem. If the user clicks on another tab (in the same browser window) and tabs back to the page, the video doesn't show. Just a box where the video should be.

Here's the page where you can see it in all its glory: **removed**

Video is MP4 H.264.

What the hell is the problem? The developer can't solve the mystery. Can you?

Comment: I don't know how to solve this, but I thought I should let you know that I use Chrome and when opening the link you provided, hovering over ''video hover" doesn't show a video... so I guess it does not failed on Safari only...

Comment: Right, I've not had that issue on all the machines I've tested on. Thanks for letting me know. If you have a sec, can you tell me what version? Oh and I just had another thought, I was uploading a fresh video resource around the time you looked at it. If you don't mind quickly checking it again, that would be a big help.

Comment: Sure, my chrome version is Version 63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Legend, thanks mate. Did you try a clear cache and refresh?

Comment: I just did and the result was the same.